# Resource leak: 'scan' is never closedJava(536871799)

Tags: java

I have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        String s = scan.next();
        
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Output:
Resource leak: 'scan' is never closedJava(536871799)

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Once you no longer need the scanner, just run `scan.close();`. That's it. Have a great day!